# Evento que não funciona para uma determinada tag sem ter que colocar id nas tags que tem que ter o evento

Tags: html5, css3

Estou fazendo uma tarefa de programação web, uma matéria que tenho no ensino médio. Nessa tarefa tenho que construir uma tabela de um cronograma de jogos de futebol, enquanto fazia decidi incrementar a tarefa com um `tr:hover` no css,  mas não consegui bloquear uma das tags `tr` de receber o evento sem ter que usar o id nas tags que eu queria o evento.

```css
tr:hover{
    background-color: #606060;
}
th{
    background-color: #707070;
}
td {
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
tfoot td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <table border="1,5" width="90%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <caption>CRONOGRAMA DE JOGOS</caption>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>DATA - DIA</th>
                <th>HORA</th>
                <th>JOGO</th>
                <th>ESTÁDIO</th>
                <th>CIDADE</th>
                <th>UF</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="5">18/07 - QUA</td><!--Esse td não pode ter o evento-->
                <td>19:30</td>
                <td>Ceará CE &times; Sport PE</td>
                <td>Castelão</td>
                <td>Fortaleza</td>
                <td>CE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21:00</td>
                <td>Vitória BA &times; Paraná PR</td>
                <td>Manoel Barradas</td>
                <td>Salvador</td>
                <td>BA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21:45</td>
                <td>Flamengo RJ &times; São Paulo SP</td>
                <td>Maracanã</td>
                <td>Rio de Janeiro</td>
                <td>RJ</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21:45</td>
                <td>Corinthians SP &times; Botafogo RJ</td>
                <td>Arena Corinthians</td>
                <td>São Paulo</td>
                <td>SP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21:45</td>
                <td>Grêmio RS &times; Atlético MG</td>
                <td>Arena do Grêmio</td>
                <td>Porto Alegre</td>
                <td>RS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="5">19/07 - QUI</td><!--Esse também não-->
                <td>19:30</td>
                <td>Cruzeiro MG &times; América MG</td>
                <td>Mineirão</td>
                <td>Belo Horizonte</td>
                <td>MG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19:30</td>
                <td>Chapecoense SC &times; Bahia BA</td>
                <td>Arena Condá</td>
                <td>Chapecó</td>
                <td>SC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20:00</td>
                <td>Vasco da Gama &times; Fluminense RJ</td>
                <td>São Januário</td>
                <td>Rio de Janeiro</td>
                <td>RJ</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20:00</td>
                <td>Santos SP &times; Palmeiras SP</td>
                <td>Pacaembu</td>
                <td>São Paulo</td>
                <td>SP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21:00</td>
                <td>Atlético PR &times; Internacional RS</td>
                <td>Arena da Baixada</td>
                <td>Curitiba</td>
                <td>PR</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><sub>Feito em 23/03/2021 às 22:00</sub></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: *"não consegui bloquear uma das tags tr de receber o evento sem ter que usar o id nas tags que eu queria o evento"* e qual é essa TR? explique melhor

Comment: Vc fala da primeira TD da TR? Vc não quer que a célula do DIA fique com o background cinza é isso?

Comment: Seria a primeira td da segunda tr e a primeira td da sétima tr. Que são td's que ocupam mais de uma linha.

Comment: Exatamente, a célula do dia não pode ter o background alterado, pois como ela ocupa mais de uma linha o evento só funciona para ela quando passa o mouse na primeira linha, o que fica estranho.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca a classe `class="dia"` na TR, e depois força a cor só na primeira TD filha `tr.dia:hover > td:first-of-type { background-color: #fff; }`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o exemplo completo

```css
tr:hover{
    background-color: #606060;
}
tr.dia:hover > td:first-of-type {
    background-color: #fff;
}
th{
    background-color: #707070;
}
td {
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
tfoot td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1,5" width="90%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <caption>CRONOGRAMA DE JOGOS</caption>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>DATA - DIA</th>
            <th>HORA</th>
            <th>JOGO</th>
            <th>ESTÁDIO</th>
            <th>CIDADE</th>
            <th>UF</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dia">
            <td rowspan="5">18/07 - QUA</td><!--Esse td não pode ter o evento-->
            <td>19:30</td>
            <td>Ceará CE &times; Sport PE</td>
            <td>Castelão</td>
            <td>Fortaleza</td>
            <td>CE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21:00</td>
            <td>Vitória BA &times; Paraná PR</td>
            <td>Manoel Barradas</td>
            <td>Salvador</td>
            <td>BA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21:45</td>
            <td>Flamengo RJ &times; São Paulo SP</td>
            <td>Maracanã</td>
            <td>Rio de Janeiro</td>
            <td>RJ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21:45</td>
            <td>Corinthians SP &times; Botafogo RJ</td>
            <td>Arena Corinthians</td>
            <td>São Paulo</td>
            <td>SP</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21:45</td>
            <td>Grêmio RS &times; Atlético MG</td>
            <td>Arena do Grêmio</td>
            <td>Porto Alegre</td>
            <td>RS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dia">
            <td rowspan="5">19/07 - QUI</td><!--Esse também não-->
            <td>19:30</td>
            <td>Cruzeiro MG &times; América MG</td>
            <td>Mineirão</td>
            <td>Belo Horizonte</td>
            <td>MG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19:30</td>
            <td>Chapecoense SC &times; Bahia BA</td>
            <td>Arena Condá</td>
            <td>Chapecó</td>
            <td>SC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20:00</td>
            <td>Vasco da Gama &times; Fluminense RJ</td>
            <td>São Januário</td>
            <td>Rio de Janeiro</td>
            <td>RJ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20:00</td>
            <td>Santos SP &times; Palmeiras SP</td>
            <td>Pacaembu</td>
            <td>São Paulo</td>
            <td>SP</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21:00</td>
            <td>Atlético PR &times; Internacional RS</td>
            <td>Arena da Baixada</td>
            <td>Curitiba</td>
            <td>PR</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"><sub>Feito em 23/03/2021 às 22:00</sub></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você não quer que **todos** os elementos tr recebam a propriedade, é melhor fazer uma classe.

Digamos que você não quer que apenas o rodapé tenha essa propriedade, ficaria assim:

```css
.classeHover:hover{
    background-color: #606060;
}
th{
    background-color: #707070;
}
td {
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
tfoot td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <table border="1,5" width="90%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <caption>CRONOGRAMA DE JOGOS</caption>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <th>DATA - DIA</th>
                <th>HORA</th>
                <th>JOGO</th>
                <th>ESTÁDIO</th>
                <th>CIDADE</th>
                <th>UF</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td rowspan="5">18/07 - QUA</td>
                <td>19:30</td>
                <td>Ceará CE &times; Sport PE</td>
                <td>Castelão</td>
                <td>Fortaleza</td>
                <td>CE</td>
            </tr class="classeHover">
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>21:00</td>
                <td>Vitória BA &times; Paraná PR</td>
                <td>Manoel Barradas</td>
                <td>Salvador</td>
                <td>BA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>21:45</td>
                <td>Flamengo RJ &times; São Paulo SP</td>
                <td>Maracanã</td>
                <td>Rio de Janeiro</td>
                <td>RJ</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>21:45</td>
                <td>Corinthians SP &times; Botafogo RJ</td>
                <td>Arena Corinthians</td>
                <td>São Paulo</td>
                <td>SP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>21:45</td>
                <td>Grêmio RS &times; Atlético MG</td>
                <td>Arena do Grêmio</td>
                <td>Porto Alegre</td>
                <td>RS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td rowspan="5">19/07 - QUI</td>
                <td>19:30</td>
                <td>Cruzeiro MG &times; América MG</td>
                <td>Mineirão</td>
                <td>Belo Horizonte</td>
                <td>MG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>19:30</td>
                <td>Chapecoense SC &times; Bahia BA</td>
                <td>Arena Condá</td>
                <td>Chapecó</td>
                <td>SC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>20:00</td>
                <td>Vasco da Gama &times; Fluminense RJ</td>
                <td>São Januário</td>
                <td>Rio de Janeiro</td>
                <td>RJ</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>20:00</td>
                <td>Santos SP &times; Palmeiras SP</td>
                <td>Pacaembu</td>
                <td>São Paulo</td>
                <td>SP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="classeHover">
                <td>21:00</td>
                <td>Atlético PR &times; Internacional RS</td>
                <td>Arena da Baixada</td>
                <td>Curitiba</td>
                <td>PR</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><sub>Feito em 23/03/2021 às 22:00</sub></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>
```

Dessa maneira, você tem liberdade absoluta pra escolher quem vai ter a propriedade ou não, só colocar nos que você quer que eles fazem parte da classe que você criou (`class="classeHover"`)

[Dê uma lida na documentação sobre classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) para aprender mais.